# No sound coming from AVPlayer

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer

I'm trying to play an mp3 (camera shutter sound) using AVPlayer. I've stripped everything down to a simple button that, when pressed, plays the sound. All of the objects are being created correctly but when I run the app on either my iPhone or iPad (both running iOS 6) no sound is generated. And no, the mute button is not on and the volume is turned up. :) I can hear sound in other apps on both devices.

Am I doing something stupid?

```
- (void)playCameraShutterSound
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Grab" withExtension:@"mp3" ];
    AVPlayer* player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'player' is released the end of method.
It must be reserved as a class variable.

Comment: this is the correct answer: player should be an ivar or property in the class

Comment: Great! Saved me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines and replace "yoursound.mp3" with your file name.:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/yoursound.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
avplayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
[avplayer play];
```